# django session random timeout

Tags: django, session, nginx, uwsgi

**I have a website, and i've been writing websites on django for a while now, but never encoutered something like this before...**

*Trouble is* that when i login everything seems alright, but as surf random pages , pretty often happens thing, that code between {% if user.is_authenticated %} {%endif %}  dissapears as i am not logged in , though i just was .

If i go back to previous page where i was logged,  before going to next page , it shows i am logged in again , and it happens completely randomly. It's not like it happens after specific actions.

Often when i try to do it on purpose everything works fine , but as some time passes something like this occurs. Though if go to login page, while it randomly shows i am logged out, it automatically logs me back because like i understand session does exist, for some reason django just does not see it .....

I am very confused what might be wrong. Any possible advice would be great.

**1)** I am not using any session functions. Basically nothing that can on purpose trigger those events. Just simple logic in views and return render_to_response('template', RequestContext(request, {}))

**2)** Django is running on *nginx* and *uwsgi*

**3)** Here is the website [site](http://www.bet-tip.net), which is currently under development, but you can login with user test, and password test to try ... maybe the same effect occurs and you'll see it.... but i do not guarentee that it will occur immidiately, it is completely random. To try u just have to click random pages..... and eventually u'll see that it shows that you logged out, though you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not give us much info to work with, and your page times out.

My best suggestion is to add the `login_required` decorator to all of your views. If you are in fact being logged out you will be able to see where this occurs.

Add the import to the top of your page, and the decorator above every view like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required(login_url='LINK_TO_LOGIN_URL')  
def first_view(request):
    # Your view code
```

You will be redirected to your login URL at any point that you are not logged in.

Once you diagnose where you are being logged out, you should be able to troubleshoot much easier. If you are able to access every view, then you can troubleshoot your templates and your `is_authenticated` code.